How do you have two different functionalities based on which different parameters was passed down to a subview
I have a subview which can take either a binding of type workout or a workout object and I want to have different functionality based on which one was passed down:
@State private var sets: [Set]

var workout: Workout

@Binding var workoutState: Workout
 
var exercise: Exercise

init(exercise: Exercise, sets: [Set], workoutState: Binding<Workout>, workout: Workout) {
    self._workoutState = workoutState
    self.workout = workout
    self.exercise = exercise
    if let newSets = exercise.sets {    //unwrapping the passed exercises sets
        if (!newSets.isEmpty) {     //we passed actual sets in so set them to our sets
            self.sets = newSets
        }
        else {      //the exercise had no sets meaning an empty array was passed so we fill it with our mock Sets
            self.sets = [Set(id: UUID(), weight: 0, reps: 0,isCompleted: false, exercise: self.exercise),Set(id: UUID(), weight: 0, reps: 0, isCompleted: false, exercise: self.exercise)]
        }
        
    }

Then I want to have different functionalities based on which of these two were passed:
  EditExeriseView(exercise: exercise, sets: exercise.sets ?? [], workoutState: $workoutState)


  EditExeriseView(exercise: exercise, sets: exercise.sets ?? [], workout: workout)

Is there any way to do this in SwiftUi without having to create two different views with different parameters?
The reason its like is because I could either navigate to this view from a list of workouts or from an add workout view where the workout is a @State object until it gets added to database

You should have only one Workout property, use some kind of boolean or state property instead

The way I am trying to make it is when the user is creating a workout as opposed to editing an existing one I want it to be local state object because I will be adding exercises to it and then when the user finishes they can click done and I write that workout state to swiftData. But the user can also edit an existing workout in which case I pass down an existing workout object I edit rather than use a @State object

For now I found the only way to do it is create two different editExericise Views one that take a workout object and one that takes a workout Binding but im trying to figure out if its possible to do that all in one view rather than create 2 different views

For example in java you would have the same constructor name but different parameters so could have different functionality based on the parameters you passed like here:
public Robot() {
    this.name = "Anonymous";
    this.model = "Unknown";
}

public Robot(String name, String model) {
    this(name, model, 20);
}


You can have multiple constructors in a view as well

but the problem is I get errors when I try to pass workout or WorkoutState (it can't exist that both get passed) and I have to pass all of the parameters in the initializer

Well your solution seems wrong from the start, you should not have two non optional properties of the same type when only one of them will be used at the same time. And why is only one a binding? Will the other not be modified? You don’t need to answer here, the questions are more for you to think about.

I am well aware im not supposed to have the non optionals there it was for demonstration purposes in my actual code I have two different views one of them takes a binding the other one takes a workout.

I would make the binding an optional and have local state properties for the various properties of the workout that you want to add/change. In onAppear you load the properties into the state properties if the binding isn't nil. When the user taps save you then either copy the state back to the bound workout, or create a new workout from the state if the binding is nil
